# Using android libraries as modules

Tags: android, module, project, android-library

In order to organize my android project, what is the best way to do this? Do I have to use `libraries` for each module, or are there a better way to create this modules? Thanks.

Comment: It depends. If you want to include external dependencies that are well maintained such as retrofit, you define them in the dependency section of the gradle.build file. (More details at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html)
Or if the repository is not available in any resource repositories you can clone the repository and import it as new module from android studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading and searching in google, I've found that making those type of modules are the best way in order to organize android projects.